# Escaping a block of text in MikTeX?

Tags: escaping, miktex

I am trying to insert a block of code into MikTeX which contains many reserved characters.  Is there any way I can escape the whole block of code so that the conversion engine does not try to evaluate it?

I suppose this would only work if the the code had balanced brackets.  Is there a way I can convert the block of text so that all individual reserved characters are escaped?

Unfortunately, being in a Windows environment seems to limit my options slightly, but if you know of a way I could achieve this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to wrap it in a `lstlisting` block?

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/listings.html

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home5/pg04878518/LatexTips.html